# Multiple column search only where column meets criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I am making a search function. I want to search where several selected columns have given value but must be restricted to where `user_id='x'`. What I have gives all results and not just where `user_id='x'` and that is what I want :

Below my query that returns everything and not just search data for `user_id='x'`

```
SELECT * FROM request 
WHERE product_name LIKE 'NDQB12%' OR request_id LIKE 'NDQB12%' 
OR batch_no LIKE 'NDQB12%' AND user_id='16';
```

Suggestions

Comment: Use parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use parentheses to separate conditions :

```
SELECT * 
FROM request 
WHERE 
     (
       (product_name LIKE 'NDQB12%') 
       OR (request_id LIKE 'NDQB12%')
       OR (batch_no LIKE 'NDQB12%')
     )
     AND user_id='16';
```

This query will show data only for the user `16` and if one of the previous conditions is True.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. I think you are not wrapping your condition right.

```
 SELECT * FROM request 
    WHERE user_id='16'
    AND (product_name LIKE 'NDQB12%' 
    OR request_id LIKE 'NDQB12%' 
    OR batch_no LIKE 'NDQB12%' )
```

Answer (score 1):

Theres a problem of precedence between your logical operations. In SQL and most programming languages, when mixing AND and OR (and maybe others) logical operators, it's always recommended to separate them with parenthesis. For your case:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    request 
WHERE 
    user_id='16' AND
    (
        product_name LIKE 'NDQB12%' OR 
        request_id LIKE 'NDQB12%' OR 
        batch_no LIKE 'NDQB12%'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from request where user_id = '16' AND 
(select * from request where product_name LIKE 'NDQB12%' OR request_id LIKE 'NDQB12%' OR batch_no LIKE 'NDQB12%')
```

Can you try if this works?

Comment: That won't work.  It will generate a syntax error.  You can't write `AND (<a sql sub-query>)`